# Dynamic CheckBoxes from JSON Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to JavaScript / JQuery and I am not sure how I could do this. Maybe a small example of each part could help.

Say I have `<div id="checkboxes"></div>`

When the page loads, I will make an ajax call that will return JSON array. This I know how to do.

The objects will be like so:

```
[
  {
    name: "Item 1",
    id: "27",
    checked: "true"
  }
  ...
]
```

I need to somehow take that JSON response and inject in some checkboxes into that div that will also store the ID. The checkbox text would be 'name'.

Then, I need to know how to attach a function for when any of these checkboxes are checked, I will need to get the 'id' at that point because I will do an ajax call when any checked changes.

Any examples of doing this sort of thing with JQuery would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Part 1 (creating the boxes):

```
$.each(json, function () {
    $("#checkboxes").append($("<label>").text(this.name).prepend(
        $("<input>").attr('type', 'checkbox').val(this.id)
           .prop('checked', this.checked)
    ));
});
```

Part 2 (dynamic fetching of ID):

```
$("#checkboxes").on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function () {
   //this is now the checkbox; this.value is the id.
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g2zaR/

Comment: How do I vertically align the checkbox label?

Comment: @Milo that is outside the scope of your question, but possibly with `vertical-align: top|bottom|middle` on the `<input>`.

Comment: Hey @ExplosionPills, how to build nested checkboxes if it contains child element as another checkbox?