# jquery dialog in yii2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii2

I have a js in yii2 like this :

```
<?php
$getDetailItem = \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['it/request/get-item-detail']);

$js = <<<JS
var \$pop = $("input[type='checkbox'][name='ItemRequest[id][]']");
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='ItemRequest[id][]']").click(function(e){
    $.ajax({
            url : '$getDetailItem',
            type : 'post',
            data : {id : $(this).val()},
            dataType : 'text',
            success : function(response){
                krajeeDialog.confirm("Your Choice : <br>" +

                    response

                , function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    alert('Anda memilih Item : ' + response);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($js)
?>
```

if you can see in the line :

```
  $getDetailItem = \Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(['it/request/get-item-detail']);
```

will be produce a json like this :

```
[{
   "id": "1",
   "item_request_id": "1",
   "nama_detail": "Create Login Novell"
}, {
   "id": "2",
   "item_request_id": "1",
   "nama_detail": "Create Email Baru"
}, {
   "id": "3",
   "item_request_id": "1",
   "nama_detail": "Disable / Hapus Login Novell"
}, {
   "id": "4",
   "item_request_id": "1",
   "nama_detail": "Disable / Hapus Email"
}]
```

My question is, how to display the response.nama_detail in dialog as checklistbox ?

I use thi krajee plugin : [kartik / krajee](http://demos.krajee.com/dialog)

Then user can choose the items nama_detail

Any help it so appreciate...

[image: Window prompt]

Answer (score 0):

Try [parsing that JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) response and format data by your needs by looping through array you will get, I used [jquery each method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for this.

Hopefully I did not make any misstake there, this is not tested, if you find any error, please feel free to comment or edit.

```
        // ...
        success : function(response){
            var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
            var output = "";
            $.each(parsed, function(index, value){
                output .= value['nama_detail'] . ", ";
            });
            krajeeDialog.confirm("Your Choice : <br>" +

                output

            , function (result) {
            if (result) {
                alert('Anda memilih Item : ' + response);
            }
        });
        // ...
```

Comment: I believe, this would display the `nama_detail` values as comma-separated text. The OP wants a "checklistbox". Obviously the response JSON needs to be parsed with `$.each()` as you have shown. Maybe this can help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15230274/3745507 to render the checkboxes dynamically

Comment: oh yes, you are right, I missed it.
Well, not sure if he wants "working" checkboxlist, because that modal might be outside of form, but he can use ussual `$form->field($model, ...` code if it is inside active form, and also would need to rewrite JS code to JsExpression I guess so he can use PHP code there